# Uploading PDF - file does not have a valid mime type in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, pdf, mime-types, dropzone.js, codeigniter-4

I am trying to upload a PDF file in my CI 4 web app but I keep getting `file does not have a valid mime type.`

I have no issues with uploading images, just PDF. I made sure I accept both in my validation.

On frontend, I use dropzone.js. I also declared that the accepted files are images and PDF.

```
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: false,
parallelUploads: 1,
maxFiles: 1,
acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf",
```

And in my controller:

```
helper(['form', 'url']);
$validateImage = $this->validate([
 'file' => [
    'uploaded[file]',
    'mime_in[file, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, application/pdf]',
    'max_size[file, 2048000]',
  ],
]);

if (!$validateImage) {
  $imageFile = $this->request->getFile('file');
  echo \Config\Services::validation()->listErrors();
  echo $imageFile->getSize(); //128373
  echo $imageFile->getMimeType(); //application/pdf
  echo $imageFile->getClientMimeType(); //application/pdf
}
```

Here's my PHP Info:

- version PHP 8.2.4
- post_max_size 20M
- upload_max_filesize 10M

The file is too light and the mime type is declared. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

So... The space in the `mime_in` is the problem. I can't express how much my ignorance disappoints me. LOL.

From:

```
mime_in[file, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, application/pdf]',
```

To:

```
mime_in[file,image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,application/pdf]',
```